# Connect IBM Conversation to Watson Workspace?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

Using Watson Workspace, I would like to talk to the bot I've built using IBM Conversation.

To do so, I tried to adapt the code from a watsonwork demo: https://github.com/watsonwork/watsonwork-echo (This demo shows how to connect an app to the Watson Workspace and echoes every 'Hello' that is written there.)
Now, instead of echoing a message, I would like to feed the message into Conversation and write back that answer into the Watson Workspace.

I assume this should be quite easy by changing the app.js at lines 32-44 to something like

```
var context = {};
conversation.message({
  workspace_id: 'workspace-id',
  input: {'text': 'Turn on the lights'},
  context: context
  },  function(err, response) {
    if (err)
      console.log('error:', err);
   else
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
});
```

API Reference: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#send_message
(And of course the authentication at the top of the file).
But this doesn't seem to work; I was not able to connect to the Conversation bot. Has anyone been doing something similar or might know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but, for some explanation I need the *error* when you try use your workspace with this repository. But, In this case you need to set your Service Credentials inside `username` and `password` variables, and not only the Workspace_id, because every Watson service created inside your IBM Bluemix have *Services Credentials*, but you can also see if you click inside the service this option.

But, I really recommend the official example from IBM developers: [conversation-simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple)
In this example you can easy set your credentials and use the project to test your conversation created (with the workspace_id), is a complete project.
And you can follow the same steps to built your app. I did.